# Get IDs of posts currently visible on archive

Tags: query, archives, post-content

This probably is a easy one for many. And also probably is already answered here, but I don't know how to search for it - so sorry I did search but not found anything.

I like to get the contents of all posts currently visible on a archive page, during `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

If I am right a good solution would be to just `get_post_field('post_content', $post_id)` for all of them.

So what I need is just the IDs for the posts that will be displayed on the current archive page. Something that involved `new WP_Query` or `query_posts` I guess, but that a area I never really touched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action fires, the main query has already run and the posts are in the global `$wp_query`. We just need to grab the ID from each object in `$wp_query->posts`, the [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) function makes that easy:

```
function wpd_get_post_ids(){
    if( is_archive() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, 'ID' );
        // $post_ids now contains an array of IDs
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_get_post_ids' );
```